# Ubuntu 16.04 QT and application menu bar

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have an application that currently runs on Ubuntu LTS 12.04, it is written in QT4. The application has multiple QDockWidgets that float on the desktop, there is a QMainWindow instance but this is usually hidden. On 12.04 the application menubar is always displayed at the top of the desktop regardless of whether the QMainWindow or a QDockWidget has focus.

On 16.04 the menubar is only visible if the QMainWindow has focus. This forces the user to find the hidden QMainWindow and select it before using the menus. The correct application name is displayed in the menubar regardless of the type of window selected.

Is there a way to restore the 12.04 behaviour either with a code change or system configuration?

Ubuntu 14.04 behaves the same way as 12.04.